# Does LZ4 compression eliminate the need for manual bit packing?

Tags: compression, lz4, bit-packing

I'm considering using LZ4 compression for a high bandwidth browser game I'm developing. I'm currently pre-compressing 1000s of float32 values down to 16bits. I'm wondering if I pre-compressed down to 12bits but saved those values as uint16s, whether LZ4 would remove the empty bits and save me the work of manually bit packing those values.

Comment: No, it's an LZ77-type compression, and those four bits that will be zero (I guess) do not have the shape of a back-match.

Comment: What sort of data patterns do have the shape of a back-match?

Comment: Repeating substrings, eg if those zero-nibbles were all in one big row instead of mixed in with the relevant data that would be fine (but they aren't, and there's no point in transforming them so they are, you might as well leave them out entirely then)